# What is fitfunc and errfunc intuitively in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I just wanted to ask you all about what is fitfunc, errfunc followed by scipy.optimize.leastsq is intuitively. I am not really used to python but I would like to understand this. Here is the code that I am trying to understand.

```
def optimize_parameters2(p0,mz):
    fitfunc = lambda p,p0,mz: calculate_sp2(p, p0, mz)
    errfunc = lambda p,p0,mz: exp-fitfunc(p,p0,mz)
    return scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(p0,mz))
```

Can someone please explain what this code is saying narratively word by word?
Sorry for being so specific but I really do have trouble understanding what it's saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular code snippet is implementing nonlinear least-squares regression to find the parameters of a curve function (this is the `fitfunc`, here) that best fit a set of data (`exp`, probably an abbreviation for "experimental data"). `leastsq()` is a somewhat more general routine for doing nonlinear least-squares optimization, not just curve-fitting. It requires a function (named `errfunc`, here) that is given a vector of parameters (`p`) and returns an array. It will attempt to find the parameter vector that minimizes the square of the returned array. In order to implement "fitting a curve to data" with `leastsq`, you have to provide an `errfunc` that evaluates the curve (`fitfunc`) at the given trial parameter vector and then subtracts it from the data (i.e. calculate the "error" or sometimes called the "residuals").

Just to be clear, none of these names are important. I'm just using them to refer to specific parts of the code snippet you provided. You will find other code that uses `leastsq()` for curve-fitting that names and organizes the code a little bit differently, but now that you know the general scheme, you should be able to follow along.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a hard time understanding it but now it makes sense!

Comment: Additional question... later in the code I see optimize_parameters2(p,mz)[0]. I am mostly confused about [0] part. What would that indicate? Would that be about the vector p??

Comment: Check the documentation for `leastsq()` to see what it returns. It returns a tuple containing the optimal `p` vector as the first element followed by additional information about the solution. The `[0]` is picking out that `p` vector and ignoring the remaining auxiliary information.

Comment: Ok.. What about p0 and mz? If p is the vector parameter, how can we describe what p0 and mz are?

Comment: They are just additional arguments needed by `calculate_sp2`. They play no special role beyond that except that they need to be passed around. It just so happens that `p0` appears to be a good initial estimate of `p`, and is so used.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports the creation of anonymous functions (i.e. functions that are not bound to a name) at runtime, using a construct called [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). In your example, `fitfunc` and `errfunc` are two such lambda functions.

I believe `calculate_sp2` and `exp_fitfunc` are simply two functions which are in the code but you didn't provide their code in the example. So, in short `fitfunc` actually calls the `calculate_sp2` function with 3 parameters `(p, p0, mz)` and returns the value which is returned by `calculate_sp2`. `errfunc` also works in the same manner.

As mentioned in official documentation of [scipy.optimize.leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html), `leastsq()` minimizes the sum of squares of a set of equations. You can learn about the parameters of `leastsq()` from the official documentation.

---

I am giving a simple example to illustrate how lambda function works.

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x,y):
    return x-y if x > y else y-x

def main(x,y):
    addition = lambda x,y: add(x,y)
    subtraction = lambda x,y: subtract(x,y)
    return addition(x,y) * subtraction(x,y)

print(main(7,4)) # prints 33 which is equal to (7+4)*(7-4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It makes sense!

Comment: @SeoyeonHong best way to thank is through accepting the answer!